# Train and test custom dataset in Facebook BlenderBot chatbot

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, blenderbot

Hope you all are having a good day.
I am working on Facebook BlenderBot Chatbot. I want to train and test my custom dataset which is in text file with text, label and episode done fields. I have created my custom dataset and added that task into tasklist. Now i want to train my dataset. There are many pretrained model for their tasks into blender model zoo. But i want to train my custom dataset. But i am not able to find how can i do it. and how can i use those pretrained models.

So please help me to solve this issue.

Thankyou

Comment: Facebook rebranded their bot as BlenderBot to distinguish it from 3D software Blender.